# IIS not serving my React SPA all I get is that the root of React app show

Tags: reactjs, iis

I did this tutorial [CRUD Operation using ASP.NET CORE 2.2 and React Redux with EntityFramework Core (Database First Approach) and PrimeReact Components](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3132485/CRUD-Operation-using-ASP-NET-CORE-2-2-and-React-Re).

It run fine in VS 2019 with IIS or local server debug. And then I publish to IIS on my Windows 10 machine. But all I get is that root layout show no routes in the browser. I have searched and can't find where the trouble is to start fixing it.

[image]

**This is what I have tried:**

I set the `basename` like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Router } from 'react-router';
import Layout from './components/Layout';
import Posts from './components/Posts';
import FormContainer from './components/FormContainer';
import ProgressIndicator from './components/ProgressIndicator';
import 'typeface-roboto';
export default () => (
    <Layout>
        <Router basename={'/ClientApp/build'}>
            <Route exact path='/' component={FormContainer} />
            <Route exact path='/' component={ProgressIndicator} />
            <Route exact path='/' component={Posts} />
        </Router>
    </Layout>
);
```

I create an web.config file in IIS wwwroot:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="ReactRouter Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(docs)" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This is Startup.cs file:

```
using BusinessLibrary.Service;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.ReactDevelopmentServer;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;

namespace AspNetCoreReactRedux
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        readonly string AllowSpecificOrigin = "_myAllowSpecificOrigin";

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
            services.AddTransient<IBooksService, BooksService>();
            // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
            });
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
                        builder =>
                        {
                            builder
                            .AllowAnyOrigin()
                            .AllowAnyMethod()
                            .AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowCredentials();
                        });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
            app.UseCors(AllowSpecificOrigin);

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.Options.StartupTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120);
                    spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I install the [URL Rewrite fro IIS](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) but i'm not sure if I was suppose to edit some settings for that

Note I change app name, here is IIS
[image]

Visual Studio 2019:

[image]

Comment: Make sure to install all the features you need.

Comment: @TheobaldDu how do I know if I miss some features in IIS? Is there som IIS log or else?